# What is the green thing in the Circuits of History?

Tags: bill-and-ted

I just watched *Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure* this evening for the first time in many years.  As they head through the Circuits of History, we see these green things on the circuits:

[image: green things on circuits]

At first, they look just like sparks (similar to the blue lightning/sparks also seen).  However, they appear to crawl around the circuits.  At one point in the movie (just after they visit the future), Bill and Ted notice the green things: Ted says, "What is that?" and Bill says, "I don't know."  We then see that they are headed for one of these green things, which looks quite monster-like, and almost reaches out to grab the phone booth:

[image: green frog-like monster]

I don't think the green monster is seen again after this, nor is it referenced in the dialog.  What is this green monster in the Circuits of History?

Comment: I always interpreted the "What is that" part to be referring to the giant loop that they whoosh through seconds later.

Comment: @Roger After watching that scene again, I think you might be right.

Comment: @Roger - Given that the green thing was added in post-production, you're almost certainly correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My good friend [Richard Malzahn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0540959/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr138) (Miniature Photography Supervisor and Software Programer for [Perpetual Motion Pictures](http://www.pmpfx.com/), the VFX house that created the 'circuits of time' sequence) was kind enough to answer this one.

Suffice to say, there's no in-universe explanation for the creature, other than that it exists between the circuits. Out of universe, it was an attempt to strengthen the tension in a scene that the studio thought was "weak".

---

I hope he won't mind me quoting the relevant parts verbatim.

> *The stupid green monster-frog-thing was the studio attempting to "fix"
> what they thought was a sequence that was "not working".  The circuits
> of time sequence was one of the first computer generated sequences in
> motion pictures.  The entire sequence was generated without the phone
> booth and then the phone booth was shot via motion control and
> composited into the shot on an optical printer.*
>
> *When the sequence was
> complete, the studio was (needlessly) nervous about the film as a
> whole and decided that the circuits of time sequence was weak, so they
> foolishly decided to add a "quick fix" which was the stupid
> green-frog-monster.*